# PHP Parsing JSON from file returns NULL values

Tags: php, json, parsing

I am trying to get some values from Arduino sensors and pass them to a php webserver to do some computations, saving them in a json file. Unfortunately I do not know much about json.
My problem is that, while the data gets correctly inserted into a JSON file, when I try to read them back out from another function, I obtain the correct key but a NULL value.
Here is the function that takes values from the POST request and saves them in a JSON file.

```
<?php 
include 'handledata.php';
//take data from POST
$light=$_POST["light"];
$temp=$_POST["temp"];

$sensors = array('light'=>$light, 'temp'=>$temp);
$fp=fopen('sensors.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($sensors));
fclose($fp);

echo "Sensor updated: calling data handler..\n";

handleData();
?>
```

This code actually works. The output sensors.json looks like this:

```
{"light":"300","temp":"22"}
```

This is the code of the handleData() function:

```
<?php
function handleData(){
    $json = file_get_contents('./sensors.json', true);
    var_dump($json);
    $sensors=json_decode($json, true);
    var_dump($sensors);
}
?>
```

The two dumps look like this:

```
string(26) "{"light":null,"temp":null}"
array(2) { ["light"]=> NULL ["temp"]=> NULL }
```

What I tried to do until now is change the json file (1st function): instead of feeding it values as strings containing numbers, I fed it a int and a string, like this:

```
$l=intval($light);
$sensors = array('light'=>$l, 'temp'=>"eight");
```

Now sensors.json looks like this:

```
{"light":793,"temp":"eight"}
```

And the output of handleData looks like this:

```
string(26) "{"light":0,"temp":"eight"}" 
array(2) { ["light"]=> int(0) ["temp"]=> string(5) "eight" }
```

I'm out of ideas on what could be the problem. With string "eight" it worked, but not with string "300". Also, am I missing something regarding the parsing of integers and numbers?
Thanks.

Comment: Amm, is this your expected output? : Sensor updated: calling data handler.. string(27) "{"light":"300","temp":"22"}" array(2) { ["light"]=> string(3) "300" ["temp"]=> string(2) "22" }

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply pass the array to the function directly?

```
handleData($sensors);
```

A function should be reusable, so expect an argument and do something with it instead of  reading contents of file inside the function.

```
<?php
    function handleData($sensors){

        var_dump($sensors);
        // do something
    }
?>
```

I've seen your comment, try this then, change $_GET to $_POST if needed.

```
<?php

    function handleData ($array) {
        var_dump($array);
        // do something later
    }

    if (!empty($_GET)) {


        file_put_contents("sensor.json", json_encode($_GET));

        handleData(json_decode(file_get_contents("sensor.json"), true));

    }


?>
```

Comment: I cannot do that, because in a more advanced state of the program, I would like to take data periodically from json files already written from other functions and parse them. So it will be something like "every 50000 seconds do: handleData()."

Answer (score 0):

Having the code tested on my localhost I used this index.php:

```
<?php 
include 'handledata.php';
//take data from POST

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $light=$_POST["light"];
    $temp=$_POST["temp"];

    $sensors = array('light'=>$light, 'temp'=>$temp);
    $fp=fopen('sensors.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($sensors));
    fclose($fp);

    echo "Sensor updated: calling data handler..\n";

    handleData();
}
?>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <input type="text" name="light" value="300" />
    <input type="text" name="temp" value="22" />
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Send!</button>
</form>
```

This gave me the following output:

`Sensor updated: calling data handler.. string(27) "{"light":"300","temp":"22"}" array(2) { ["light"]=> string(3) "300" ["temp"]=> string(2) "22" }`

Comment: Could you tell me what your sensors.json looks like after storing the POST values? Do you know what should change if I store values that way or by any other POST request?

Comment: yea sure: {"light":"300","temp":"22"}

Comment: Being this the same and only creating my own form to simulate the submit.. I think it might be a php.ini problem about the json_encode/decode or something.. couldn't think of anything else. To test this is positive, you should test it on a webserver and localserver and see what's different